# R - converting dates within data.frame

Tags: r

I am working with a "`data.frame`" which are given in the following formate:   Aug 12, 2017.

```
class(data[,1]) = factor
```

How can i convert these into dates?

`data[,1] <- as.Date.factor(data[,1],format = "%m.%d.%y")`, returns `NA`'s.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the package `lubridate` for very easy to use functions to operate with dates. For example:

```
mdy("Aug 12,2017")
[1] "2017-08-12"
```

If your date is in YYYY-MM-DD format, you can use the `ymd` function. There are also other functions such as `dmy`, `dmy_hms` (for datetime), etc.

If your column is called `my.date`, you can do:

```
data$my.date <- mdy(data$my.date)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `%<>%` operator from `magrittr` to make your code even shorter:

```
data$my.date %<>% mdy
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `as.POSIXct` (Base-R Solution):

```
as.POSIXct("Aug 12,2017", format="%b%d,%Y")
```

Output:

```
[1] "2017-08-12 CEST"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `strptime`, could work:

```
strptime("Aug 12,2017", "%b%d,%Y")
```

Output:

```
[1] "2017-08-12 UTC"
```

The second parameter for `strptime` is the format of the dates you have. For instance, if your dates are like this `"1/5/2005"`, then the format would be:

```
format="%m/%d/%Y"
```

Hope it helps