# Change factor to Datetime in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a factor variable which I would to transform in Date. When I try using `as.Date()` It shows me the error:

> Error in charToDate(x) : 
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

My data are these:

```
[1] Aug 31, 2018 Aug 30, 2018 Aug 29, 2018 Aug 28, 2018 Aug 27, 2018 Aug 26, 2018
[7] Aug 25, 2018 Aug 24, 2018 Aug 23, 2018 Aug 22, 2018 Aug 21, 2018 Aug 20, 2018
[13] Aug 19, 2018 Aug 18, 2018 Aug 17, 2018 Aug 16, 2018 Aug 15, 2018 Aug 14, 2018
[19] Aug 13, 2018 Aug 12, 2018 Aug 11, 2018 Aug 10, 2018 Aug 09, 2018 Aug 08, 2018
[25] Aug 07, 2018 Aug 06, 2018 Aug 05, 2018 Aug 04, 2018 Aug 03, 2018 Aug 02, 2018
```

How could I transform in Date in the format `%d-%m-%Y`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - converting dates within data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222856/r-converting-dates-within-data-frame)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `format = "%b %d, %Y"`:

```
ss <- c("Aug 31, 2018", "Aug 30, 2018", "Aug 29, 2018", "Aug 28, 2018", "Aug 27, 2018", "Aug 26, 2018")

as.Date(ss, format = "%b %d, %Y")
#[1] "2018-08-31" "2018-08-30" "2018-08-29" "2018-08-28" "2018-08-27"
#[6] "2018-08-26"
```

For details what the different conversion specifications (e.g. `"%b"`, `"%Y"` etc.) mean, take a look at `?strptime`.

By the way, there is no need to manually convert from `factor` to `character`, because `as.Date` has a method for `factor`s which converts `factor`s to `character` vectors, see `as.Date.factor`.

Comment: It doesn't work, It seems it doesn't recognize May and June. It turns out NAs!

Answer (score 0):

specify the format within the function as.Date

```
as.Date(MyData, format="%b %d, %Y")
```

Comment: It gives me a lot of NAs and some good data. It seems that doesn't recognize some months of the Year, like May and June.

Comment: Could you show us how your format of the days in May and June looks like?

Comment: The format is the same as for the other months. It looks like:  **May 19, 2018**. The format is the same for all of these ('"%m %d, %Y"'), but for some months it turns NAs.

Comment: I could imagine that your language settings are not English... therefore it doesn't recognize "May" -> look herefor more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031002/get-weekdays-in-english-in-r

Comment: You were right! It was in Italian! I solved the problem simply getting 'Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")' in the console! Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem getting this code `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")` into the console!